# Reading the content-length and Content-Type

Tags: node.js

How can I read in the node the incoming content-length and content-Type.

I saw the 
http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.6.6/api/all.html#request.connection

Looks i am missing some thing.

How can I read the Content-length and content -type and any other general headers? like X-*

Answer (score 0):

```
req.headers
```

This field will be populated with all headers sent. If you want to access the Connection-header, use:

```
req.headers.connection
```

Content-Length and Content-Type are headers only sent when a body is present, so they are not sent with a GET request.

Comment: not really PUT ans\d POST which are requests can contain the Content-Length and Content-Type headers.

Comment: yes. I am looking how to read the content-type and content-length for these Requests. I want my Node to read these headers and than do some processing